# nested accordian children not closing after parent is close

Tags: javascript

i am working on nested accordion.i want when i close my parent accordion,opened child accordion automatically close.
here is my javaScript functions:

```
    var accc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var panell = document.getElementsByClassName('panel1');
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_inner");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel2');

    for (var i = 0; i < accc.length; i++) {
        accc[i].onclick = function () {
           var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
            setClass(accc, 'active', 'remove');
          setClass(panell, 'show', 'remove');

           if (setClasses) {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
           }
       }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function () {
            var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
            setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
            setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

            if (setClasses) {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    }function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].classList[fnName](className);
        }
   }function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
       for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
           els[i].classList[fnName](className);
       }
   }
```

Comment: post the html too or make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/5/

Comment: you missed a class on the last panel see this if its what you want https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/6/

Comment: i want when i close heading1 its children heading 1.2 should automatically close

Comment: add `setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');` after `setClass(panell, 'show', 'remove');` this will hide child panel of child accordion

Comment: Thanku so much  !! Worked perfect :) :)